# Access append query inconsistent

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table creation query (combine2) which takes a query (combine) and makes it a table (linegraph). This table must reflect changes in the associated query.  Currently I have assigned a macro to run the append query to reflect changes.

The problem is that no matter how the `append query` is called it sometimes but not always copies all the data.  Sometimes it wont import the first 100 or so rows.  How can I get an updating table that always matches my query?

**Append Query: Combine2**

```
INSERT INTO linegraph SELECT * FROM Combine;
```

**Query to turn into table: Combine**

```
SELECT * FROM Month1calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month2calc UNION
SELECT * FROM month3calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month4calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month5calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month6calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month7calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month8calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month9calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month10calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month11calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month12calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month13calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month14calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month15calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month16calc UNION
SELECT * FROM Month17calc UNION 
SELECT * FROM Month18calc;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

When you use `UNION`, the query only returns *unique* rows (i.e.: duplicates are removed). When you use `UNION ALL`, duplicates are not removed.